# Data Looks good in Power Query Editor but only showing cells with 0 values in Table View

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, business-intelligence

I'm currently learning Power BI and attempting to do a little project, I prepared the data by myself, after loading into the Query Editor for transformation et al. Everything looks good, but when I switch to Table view to build my visualization, it only shows 0 values and skip some of the data, any explanation why this is happening and suggestions on how to fix will help. I attach a screenshot for better comprehension.[image: Before Loading]

[image: After Loading]

Comment: strange, I assume you did hit the "Refresh" button?

Comment: I refreshed a few times after I noticed the 0 values

Comment: I've seen this commonly when there is an issue with datatypes in the Power Query code. But with neither a data set (as **text**) nor the code, I can't tell you much more.

Comment: I don't really know my way around s/o that much, I couldn't find a place to attach my file, if I had to type out the data, it will take time and it will be the same as the first picture attached as that's what I see on excel.

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake, I didn't scroll all the way down, I expected the data to be sorted by `Date` column by default, but it sorted by the `Threes` column, that's why I got all the 0's first.